# Excel Add-in: Disable/Enable Ribbon button - ControlIdNotFound

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I am trying to Disable/Enable custom ribbon button and getting a `RichApi.Error: ControlIdNotFound`.

Here is the code for Disable: (exactly same for Enable except `true`)

```
function disableAddNewBAButton() {
  try {
    var button = {
      id: "AddNewBAButton",
      enabled: false,
    };
    var parentGroup = {
      id: "CommandsGroup",
      controls: [button],
    };
    var parentTab = {
      id: "TabHome",
      groups: [parentGroup],
    };
    var ribbonUpdater = { tabs: [parentTab] };
    Office.ribbon.requestUpdate(ribbonUpdater);

    addNewBAButtonEnabled = false;
    console.log(addNewBAButtonEnabled);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Disable Add New BA Button Error:" + error.stack);
  }
}
```

I have taken the `parentTab = { id: "TabHome", }` from the manifest under: `<OfficeTab id="TabHome">`.

The `parentGroup = { id: "CommandsGroup", }` from the manifest under: `<Group id="CommandsGroup">`.

The `button = { id: "AddNewBAButton", }` from the manifest under: `<Control xsi:type="Button" id="AddNewBAButton">`.

I'm stuck as to why `ControlIdNotFound`. Am i getting the ID from the wrong place?

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: All of the examples at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/disable-add-in-commands are cases where the group and the tab (as well as the button) are custom. Please see if it works when the button is in a custom group and the group is on a custom tab. The results might help pinpoint what's going wrong.

Comment: @RickKirkham thanks rick, i actually managed to solve this by generating a new yoeman add-in and got it working on the blank add-in. Then went back to my original add-in and it started working.. didnt change anything but was successful. Quite strange but if it works....